# 5g authentication method for IoT

Tags: networking, authentication, 5g

While i was studying authentication methods in 5g i bumped into 3 authentication methods that seems to be the most important ones: 5G-AKA,EAP-AKA,EAP-TLS.

Which one of these three could be more suitable for an IoT environment? I've read that EAP-TLS is the most expensive one in terms of required power/maintentance cost.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is simply too broad to answer. Each method has its advantages/disadvantages, and we have no information about your implementation. Also, depending on your equipment, ISP, etc. you may not even have a choice.